# Find the oldest email in inbox, outlook

Tags: vba, email, date, outlook

I need to get an msgbox which shows me the date of the oldest email in the inbox in outlook, but I can't find it though I've tried roughly.

I know it must be a simple sentence but I am not able to find it.

Please would anyone give me any hint? Just a simple code...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
set folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
set items = folder.Items
items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", false
set oldestMessage = items.GetFirst
Msgbox oldestMessage.Subject & " " & oldestMessage.ReceivedTime
```